# Moment.js returning incorrect value from MySQL datetime

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, momentjs

[image: MariaDB datetime in field createdAt 5 days off using moment.js library]

[image: UTC to CST conversions]

When fetching data from a MySQL DB (MariaDB dialect) column `createdAt` in the schema above is being returned 5 days off. The records were logged into the database on 2018-01-26 9:41 AM & 9:29 AM, along with another record on 2018-01-22 12:51 PM.

Code that I am using to log the results in the console is:

```
   let test = moment(post.createdAt)
   console.log('test', test)
```

post.createdAt is within a map function and is supposed to return the correct converted time of each record within the query (In this case 3 records in the screen shot above in the DB)

Examples:

```
moment(post.createdAt) // 2018-01-22 18:53:15
  returns to client console.log:  2018-01-17T18:35:56.000Z

moment(post.createdAt) // 2018-01-26 15:29:41
  returns to client console.log:  2018-01-21T18:36:23.000Z

moment(post.createdAt) // 2018-01-26 15:41:49
  returns to client console.log:  2018-01-21T18:36:23.000Z
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why is the date being returned to the client 5 days prior to when it was actually logged into the DB?
2. What is the proper way to return the correct date and time? I have tried

   moment(post.createdAt).utc()

   moment.tz(post.createdAt)

   moment.parseZone(post.createdAt)

with no success. The client in the left, I just added 5 days to the date to return the correct date, but this does not seem like a scaleable approach, I am completely stuck to how to convert the time from what is logged into the database to CST (Chicago/America)

Would anyone explain the error I am making? Also the datatype for the column `createdAt datetime NOT NULL`.

Comment: Need to see some actual code and values, not pictures of values.

Comment: OK, apologies.I added what I am using to log the dates in the console in the code snippet above.

Comment: You're missing the point. What is the actual value of `post.createdAt`?

Comment: ok updated again, does that above make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate your issue. Test code below.

```js
console.log(moment('2018-01-22 18:53:15'));
console.log(moment('2018-01-26 15:29:41'));
console.log(moment('2018-01-26 15:41:49'));

console.log(moment('2018-01-22 18:53:15').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(moment('2018-01-26 15:29:41').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(moment('2018-01-26 15:41:49').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```